# Multilevel numbered headings in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I have a large document with multilevel numbered headings

> 4.1.7. Level 3 heading
>   4.2. Level 3 heading
>   4.2.1. Level 3 heading

I noticed this  `4.2. level 3 heading` there that really should be level 2 heading. I changed it to level 2 by using the appropriate style.

Then the "4.2.1" changes to "4.1.8":

> 4.1.7. Level 3 heading
>   4.2. Level 2 heading
>   4.1.8. Level 3 heading

What can be done to fix it?

I tried changing the third heading to level 2 and back to level 3 - the number changes to 4.2.1 - but all the rest of the level 3 headings after it remain with their wrong numbers.

Comment: Change the start from number for `4.1.8. Level 3 heading` to `4.2.1`

Comment: @DavidPostill - thank you! I wonder why it does not automatically make the next heading follow the numbering, even if I choose "continue the previous list" in the right-click menu (I'm using the Russian version, so my phrasing might not fit the English phrasing exactly).

Comment: Word has always been a bit odd in how it handles numbering of lists ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What can be done to fix it?

You need to change the start from number for "4.1.8. Level 3 heading" to `4.2.1`

> 1. Click the dropdown on the right hand side of the Numbering button on the ribbon.
> 2. Select "Set Numbering Value..."
> 3. Tick the check box "Start a new list".
> 4. Enter the start value in the "Set value to" box.
> 5. Click "OK".

Source [Numbering In Word 2007 how to start a numbered list at a number other than 1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/numbering-in-word-2007-how-to-start-a-numbered/8389dc68-66dd-4583-82d6-9a6d8b547cfd)